# Google Maps API V3, Listener is behaving strangely

Tags: google-maps-api-3, listener

I have created a bunch of markers and infoboxes that I want to link together trough a listener, though the listener seems to fire at start without any click, and if I try to fire the listener with a click on the marker(after closing the box)  nothing ever happens.

```
//Load Markers
function LoadData() {
    //Space Reservation
    var site_arr  = new Array();
    var point_arr = new Array();
    var pasta_arr = new Array();
    //Load All Information
    point_arr = [new google.maps.LatLng(38.629343,-9.191592),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(38.649187,-9.189205)];

    site_arr = ["AAA","BBB"];

    pasta_arr = [1,2];

    //Create Markers and Set InfoBoxes
    for(var i = 0 ; i < site_arr.length ; i++){
        marker_arr[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: point_arr[i]
               ,map: map
               ,title: site_arr[i]
                });

            window_arr[i] = new InfoBox({
             content: site_arr[i]
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_arr[i], 'click', function(i){
           window_arr[i].open(map,marker_arr[i]);
            }(i));
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone has any idea of what is going on?

Solved the problem, I'm just posting it because it might be useful for others...
Thanks everyone!

//Load Markers
function LoadData() {
    //Space Reservation
    var site_arr  = new Array();
    var point_arr = new Array();
    var pasta_arr = new Array();
    //Load All Information
    point_arr = [new google.maps.LatLng(38.629343,-9.191592),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(38.649187,-9.189205)];

```
site_arr = ["AAA",
            "BBB"];

pasta_arr = [1,2];

//Create Markers and Set InfoBoxes
for(i = 0 ; i < site_arr.length ; i++){
    marker_arr[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point_arr[i]
        ,map: map
        ,title: site_arr[i]
        ,icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
    });

    marker_arr[i]._info = new InfoBox({
         content: pasta_arr[i];
    });
    attachListener(marker_arr[i]);
}
return 0;
```

}

function attachListener(marker){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        marker._info.open(map,marker);
    });
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding a function to your listener, but a function value. You display the info windows because you evaluate the listener's `function(i)` at `i` during `LoadData()`. The second problem is that even if you remove the evaluation you will not get the intended index `i` during the call of the listener. The correct way is something like:

```
marker_arr[i]._info = window_arr[i];
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_arr[i], 'click', function() {
    var marker = this;
    marker._info.open(map, marker);
});
```

Comment: I now do understand why the listener is firing on its own, but still your suggestion won't work either, now whatever the marker that is clicked the infobox is displayed with the informations of the last marker, and in the last marker position!

Comment: My first answer was a suggestion. I improved it now such that it is fully working.